# Download a file to internal storage using AsyncTask - Android

Tags: android, download, android-asynctask, storage, internal

This may be a simple question but I have not found very detailed documentation on how to do this but that is why I am here. How do you download a file from the internet into the internal storage from an AsyncTask. I ask this because I need a file downloaded to update variable strings as so information can be updated easily and I was going to just use InputStream but that would mean the user has to use the internet to get the information back everytime the app is restarted. Any information or guide on how to do this would be very helpful and the file in question that needs downloading when the AsyncTask is called is here:

http://nowactivity.webs.com/teststring.txt

Keep in mind that that isn't what the text is going to actually say :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3028660/1276374

Comment: This may help you 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog